# Polymer not working Firefox - document.registerElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Web page loads fine on Google.
I've heard using webcomponents.js is supposed to fix the issue by using Polyfill but I can't seem to figure our what is wrong.
Code in the header of my index.html file

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Firefox Console output

> TypeError: document.registerElement is not a function[Learn More]
>       TypeError: Polymer.Base._getExtendedPrototype is not a function[Learn More]
>       TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a function[Learn More]
>       TypeError: Polymer.Base._getExtendedPrototype is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polymer sample code not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526642/polymer-sample-code-not-working-in-firefox)